# Regex capturing inside a group

Tags: sql, regex

I working on a method to get all values based on a SQL query and then scape them in php.

The idea is to get the programmer who is careless about security when is doing a SQL query.

So when I try to execute this:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (a, b,c,d) VALUES ('a','b','c',a,b)
```

The regex needs to capture `'a' 'b' 'c' a` and `b`

I was working on this a couple of days.

This was as far I can get with 2 regex querys, but I want to know if there is a better way to do:

```
VALUES ?\((([\w'"]+).+?)\)
```

Based on the previous SQL this will match:

```
VALUES ('a','b','c',a,b)
```

The second regex

```
['"]?(\w)['"]?
```

Will match

```
a b c a b
```

Previously removing `VALUES`, of course.

This way will match a lot of the values I gonna insert.

But doesn't work with JSON for example.

```
{a:b, "asd":"ads" ....}
```

Any help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you should know that SQL support many types of single/double quoted string:
`'Northwind\'s category name'`
`'Northwind''s category name'`
`"Northwind \"category\" name"`
`"Northwind ""category"" name"`
`"Northwind category's name"`
`'Northwind "category" name'`
`'Northwind \\ category name'`
`'Northwind \ncategory \nname'`

to match them, try with these patterns: 
`"[^\\"]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^\\"]*)*"`
`'[^\\']*(?:(?:\\.|'')[^\\']*)*'`

combine patterns together:

```
VALUES\s*\(\s*(?:"[^\\"]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^\\"]*)*"|'[^\\']*(?:(?:\\.|'')[^\\']*)*'|\w+)(?:\s*,\s*(?:"[^\\"]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^\\"]*)*"|'[^\\']*(?:(?:\\.|'')[^\\']*)*'|\w+))*\)
```

PHP5.4.5 sample code:

```
    <?php
$pat = '/\bVALUES\s*\((\s*(?:"[^\\"]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^\\"]*)*"|\'[^\\\']*(?:(?:\\.|\'\')[^\\\']*)*\'|\w+)(?:\s*,\s*(?:"[^\\"]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^\\"]*)*"|\'[^\\\']*(?:(?:\\.|\'\')[^\\\']*)*\'|\w+))*)\)/';
$sql_sample1 = "INSERT INTO tabla (a, b,c,d) VALUES ('a','b','c',a,b)";
if( preg_match($pat, $sql_sample1, $matches) > 0){
    printf("%s\n", $matches[0]);
    printf("%s\n\n", $matches[1]);    
}

$sql_sample2 = 'INSERT INTO tabla (a, b,c,d) VALUES (\'a\',\'{a:b, "asd":"ads"}\',\'c\',a,b)';
if( preg_match($pat, $sql_sample2, $matches) > 0){
    printf("%s\n", $matches[0]);
    printf("%s\n", $matches[1]);    
}

?>
```

output:

```
VALUES ('a','b','c',a,b)
'a','b','c',a,b

VALUES ('a','{a:b, "asd":"ads"}','c',a,b)
'a','{a:b, "asd":"ads"}','c',a,b
```

If you need to get each value from result, split by `,` (like parsing CSV)

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Seems to work great!!! amazing regex :P Thanks a lot! I will try a bit more! thanks!